# Segmentation fault while creating a file with setfsuid()?

Tags: c, file, permissions, segmentation-fault

I have this c code that creates a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("/home/sss/test3.file","w");
    fprintf(fp, "hi hi hi\n" );
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;   
}
```

When I added the setfsuid() command before file fopen() call and executed the program, I am getting a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#incldde <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    setfsuid(1002);
    fp=fopen("/home/sss/test3.file","w");
    fprintf(fp, "hi hi hi\n" );
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;   
}
```

The setfsuid() command needs root permissions and I am on a linux system with server OS. What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the result of `fopen` and make sure it is not `NULL`. `setfsuid` changes the `UID` used for filesystem access checks. After this change, you likely do not have permissions to open that file for writing, resulting in `fopen` returning NULL. This causes a `segfault` when you attempt to write to the file with `fprintf`. **Always check return values before using them.**